# MVC Localication set culture in httpmodule

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, localization

I have implemented Localization on my MVC3 Application.

i am looking for a solution to setup the current culture before the ActionFilterAttribute is executed.

i would like to get the the current culture from the url:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Language",
                "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { culture = "en", controller = "Page", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

in the base controller i can do:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var culture = filterContext.RouteData.Values["culture"] ?? ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DefaultCulture"];
            var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo((string)culture);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
```

i would like to update the application and setup the current culture in the httpmodule

at the moment my code looks like this:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication httpApplication)
        {
            httpApplication.BeginRequest += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                var defaultCulture = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DefaultCulture"];
                CultureInfo cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(defaultCulture);
                try
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
                }
                catch { }
            };
        }
```

how can i setup the current culture using the filterContext.RouteData.Values["culture"] in the httpmodule ?

Thank you in advanced for any help

Ori

Answer (score 1):

You should use a custom route handler to set the culture accordingly to the route information. See example below:

```
public class CultureMvcRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (requestContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("requestContext");
        }

        string culture = requestContext.RouteData.Values["culture"] as string ?? "";
        CultureInfo ci = CreateCultureInfo(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }

    private CultureInfo CreateCultureInfo(string culture)
    {
        if (culture == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("culture");
        }

        CultureInfo ci = null;

        try
        {
            ci = new CultureInfo(culture);
        }
        catch (CultureNotFoundException)
        {
            ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        }

        return ci;
    }
}
```